# Unable to Upload file into Amazon s3 bucket

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3

I would be thankful if someone help me out in solving this issue.

I am using codeigniter framwork for my project. And Want to upload my image into amazon s3 bucket. When i am trying to use the S3.php file & putObjectfile() for uploading I am getting the error as

> string(92) "The authorization mechanism you have provided is not
>   supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256."

Can someone help me out in solving this issue.

Comment: Could you please share you code for authentication against Amazon S3

Comment: if (!class_exists('S3'))require_once('S3.php');
   if (!defined('awsAccessKey')) define('awsAccessKey', 'CHANGE THIS');
   if (!defined('awsSecretKey')) define('awsSecretKey', 'CHANGE THIS TOO');
   $s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
   if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $fileName = $_FILES['theFile']['name'];
    $fileTempName = $_FILES['theFile']['tmp_name'];
    
    //create a new bucket
    $s3->putBucket("yourbucket", S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
    if ($s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName, "yourbucket", $fileName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) { }

Comment: Okay, I Posted my answer

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following:

```
$s3Client = S3Client::factory(array('key'=>YOUR_AWS_KEY, 'secret'=>YOUR_AWS_SECRET, 'signature' => 'v4'));
```